# Rapid Shutter Release (<1 ms)

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera

I’m looking for a full frame DSLR camera that can take 3 shots at full resolution in less than 4ms (total), with a USB 3.0+ interface. Ideally, a Nikon. Any leads would be much appreciated.

Comment: Clarification: I need to shoot 3 photos in 4ms or less — a high frame rate video (even at 4K) will not work.

Comment: *No idea* if it's even possible, I don't shoot digital. But I know that fast image processing requires a fast SD, so look into that :)

Comment: OT, but: 3 shots in 4ms = 1 shot in 1.3 ms = **770 fps**. No off-the-shelf picture-taking camera can do that; you will need a high speed videocamera, e.g. a [Phantom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phantom_(high-speed_camera_brand))

Comment: Voting to close this as a product rec, short lived with no value. BUT - I would love to retract that vote and think this would be a great question with lots of good answers...IF you asked how to solve the actual problem instead and gave  the 3 shots as a constraint.

Comment: Some exilim compacts had (low resolution) high speed modes...

Answer (score 5):

3 full photos in only 4ms is well outside the realm of current mainstream DSLR camera specifications as of 2019.

Your options will be limited to fairly advanced scientific grade gear, or using multiple cameras set up in a chain-firing method.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-speed_photography

You will likely need to seek rotary mirror/prism setups if you require sighting through a single lens.

I have worked with a custom rig to connect off the shelf modern digital cameras to a rotary prism, where all the cameras were set with a 'long' shutter speed that fired at once, and the actual exposure was then controlled by the lens and prism assembly, but I would have to go digging to see if anyone actually sells such a device.